# output to file c programming

Tags: c, file, struct, output

I have an array of outputs that were generated in a model with a  source code file that is linked to it. It is referenced here as

```
struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];
```

in the following function I have written. I'm just trying to put these outputs generated from another function

```
output[i].d[5]
```

in a file for me to work with in my Python program. I'll eventually need it to be a csv file in Python, so if anyone knows how to directly make it a .csv that would be awesome, but I haven't found a successful method for that so .txt is fine. Here is what I have so far, when I run the code and the output file I'm getting the format I want, but the numbers in the output are way off. (Values of 10^-100 when I'm working with 10^-9). Can anyone tell why this is happening? Also, I already tried putting the outputs in a separate array and then calling from that array but it didn't work. I may not have done it correctly however, this project is the first time I've had to use C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "nrlmsise-00.h"

#define ARRAYLENGTH 10
#define ARRAYWIDTH 7

void test_gtd7(void) {
    int i;


    struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];
    for (i=0;i<ARRAYLENGTH;i++)
        gtd7(&input[i], &flags, &output[i]);
    for (i=0;i<ARRAYLENGTH;i++) {
        printf("\nRHO   ");
        printf("   %2.3e",output[i].d[5]);
        printf("\n");
    //The output prints accurately with this.
    }
    }

void outfunc(void){

    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH]; //I may be calling the      output wrong here
    fp=fopen("testoutput.txt","w");
     if(fp == NULL)
        {
        printf("There is no such file as testoutput.txt");
        }
    fprintf(fp,"RHO");
    fprintf(fp,"\n");


    for (i=0;i<ARRAYLENGTH;i++) {

        fprintf(fp, "%E", output[i].d[5]);
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
        }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n%s file created","testoutput.txt");
    printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: and also in the function wheere the output is generated, the output struct is called like this `struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];`    `for (i=0;i<ARRAYLENGTH;i++){
                    gtd7(&input[i], &flags, &output[i]);` and I'm only using 1 of the output variables ( `output[i].d[5]`).

Comment: Please include definition of `struct nrlmsise_output`

Comment: Yes, include the struct definition and also edit your post instead of adding new code to comments

Comment: Where is that? Also someone made and removed a comment asked how `output` is populated, which you commented instead of showing the complete function. `output` is a local variable, so it makes no sense to say you filled it in somewhere else (such as in a comment). There is only one relevant line in the code `fprintf(fp, "%E", output[i].d[5]);` but you tell us nothing about it except it does not work.

Comment: Okay is this what you mean? I have a feeling I am accessing output in the second function incorrectly.

Comment: "There is no such file as testoutput.txt" is not a helpful error message.  Try: `char *path="testoutput.txt"; fp = fopen(path,"w");  if(fp == NULL) {perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}` 2 major benefits: it tells you why `fopen` failed, and it prints the error message on the correct stream. (Errors do not belong on stdout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variables `output` are not seen outside of the functions in which they are declared and used. The variables `output` in each of your two functions are unrelated except by having the same name: they do not hold the same data.

You need to either declare `output` as a global array, or pass the array to `test_gtd7()`

```
void test_gtd7(struct nrlmsise_output *output) {
    ...
}

void outfunc(void) {
    struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];
    ...
    test_gtd7(&output);
    ...
}
```

**OR**

```
struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];         // gobal array

void test_gtd7() {
    //struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];   // remove
    ...
}

void outfunc(void) {
    //struct nrlmsise_output output[ARRAYLENGTH];   // remove
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the first option, you might need to edit the way you access the array passed as an argument, mybad I didn't get into it.

Comment: Oh no I had other structs in that function to call I just left them out on here that's why I think haha.